# Is there an Instagram API/Graph API for finding the Instagram Profile Type (Business/Personal)?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using the Graph API to get details from business users. Since most of the Profile is Non-Business, would like to find-out, if there is an API to get the Profile Type?

During the trial, I keep getting the following message and also discovered sometime the API is misbehaving..

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid user id",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 110,
        "error_subcode": 2207013,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Cannot find User",
        "error_user_msg": "The user with username: rohit_xxx cannot be found.",
        "fbtrace_id": "FkKgUvBdJWZ"
    }
}
```

So, If I know the Profile Type in advance, We can handle the response in much better way..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instagram Graph API is designed to work with creator/business accounts. This is specified in multiple places.

If a user doesn't have business/creator account, the instagram id would be empty in the response.

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{fb-page-id}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={access-token}"
```

Response:

```
{   
  "instagram_business_account": {
      "id": ""  // Connected IG User ID   
},   
  "id": "134895793791914"  // Facebook Page ID 
}
```